# Does having two different models improve performance for underrepresented classes?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, class-imbalance, object-detection, yolo

I am currently working on a dataset that has approximately 7000 annotations, but suffers from severe class imbalance (there are 1331 annotations for the most represented class, and 77 for the least represented one).

I tried using image weights when training using YOLOv5's "--image-weights" argument, but that did not make much of a difference as I was still overfitting quickly on some classes (but not all of them) - so I was wondering whether it would improve the results if I split the model into two different models. Theoretically, this would allow me to train for longer for some classes, and for less for some others.

Before I invest any time in rewriting the architecture, is there even any sense in doing this, or am I on a completely wrong path?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ensemble usually works well. Often too well, to the point that their performance often fall under the term 'magic' or 'mystery'. See here for exemple: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/blog/three-mysteries-in-deep-learning-ensemble-knowledge-distillation-and-self-distillation/. It's not easy to explain how ensemble perform well in general. So it is very difficult to answer regarding your specific problem (imbalance) in your specific case (YOLOV5). Unfortunately you are left with a very empirical approach (try and see if it works), for which we can't really help.

Comment: Thank you @Icrmorin, I was not aware of this technique - it looks very useful. I will look into it immediately.